# Taskbar icon opens the wrong Active form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Having a strange behaviour with my application whereby when navigation between web browser (or any other application) and clicking back into the application seems to open the wrong `Form`? So user literally has to make use of `Tab` window to open the correct `Form`.

For e.g. `Form1` is the main form. User clicks a button which opens `Form2`. `Form1` is hidden behind the scene while `Form2` opens. Now if user goes to a different application e.g. browser and clicks back into the application `Form1` is displayed and there is no other way of going back to `Form2` without the Tab window?

I have used the `.ShowDialog()` property when opening `Form2` which disabled the parent form `Form1` but still seems to do it occasionally?!?

I have also set the `ShowInTaskBar` for Form2 to `False` so that there is one icon in taskbar for all forms.

Not really sure what can cause this behaviour to happen?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell Form2 who its owner form is.

Like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Owner = this;
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

see [System.Windows.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=netframework-4.8)  for more information

Answer (score 0):

When you open form2, you need set mdiParent of form1.

First, set form1 as "isMdiParent" to "true" in properties, and then use the follow code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.MdiParent = this;
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: There is no indication the OP has an MDI Parent.